# Javascript Button irresponsive to tasks

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a button on my website. It is supposed to write to firebase database. However it is irresponsive. It appears that the button can be found using my code. I tried adding alert("hello world"), but it is still irresponsive. The ids corresponds to the get element as well.

Code

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
</div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                           
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
    
            </div>
        </div>
  
    <script type = "module">
            const firebaseConfig = {
              apiKey: "***",
              authDomain: "***",
              databaseURL: "***",
              projectId: "***",
              storageBucket: "***",
              messagingSenderId: "***",
              appId: "***",
              measurementId: "***"
            };
          
            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            var firebaseRef=firebase.database().ref('quotes');
    
            
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener('click', function(){
                //PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE
                alert("hello world");
                var id=Date.now();  //generating a unqiue id
                const companyName=document.getElementById('cname').value;
                const grade=document.getElementById('grade').value;
                const concrete=document.getElementById('concrete').value;
                const formWorks=document.getElementById('formworks').value;
                const wall=document.getElementById('wall').value;
                const excavation = document.querySelector('.excavation:checked').value;
                const typeWork=document.getElementById("typeWork")
                const paint = document.querySelector('.paint:checked').value;
                const comments=document.getElementById('comments').value;
                const total=document.getElementById('total').value;
                firebaseRef.child(id).push({
                   companyName:companyName,
                   grade:grade,
                   concrete:concrete,
                   formWorks:formWorks,
                   wall:wall,
                   excavation:excavation,
                   typeWork:typeWork,
                   paint:paint,
                   comments:comments,
                   total:total
                });
            });
        </script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: `document.getElementById("#btnSubmit")` should be `document.getElementById("btnSubmit")` (there is no `#` in the actual id attribute you're looking for). But then I also do not see such a button with this ID - or indeed any elements at all - produced by your code, so maybe that's another problem.

Comment: <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                          
                        </tr>